# Why isn't calling time.localtime() every 5 seconds incrementing time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am writing data points to a database and have a loop that creates points.  I have it `sleep(5)` in order to increment time by 5 seconds.  Below is the relevant code block although really only the line related to time matters:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    points = []
    #local = time.localtime()
    for x in range(0,5):
        points.append(Point("biz_intel").tag("region", random.choice(regions)) \
                            .tag("app",random.choice(apps)) \
                            # .tag("host",host) \
                            .field("user_sessions", random.choice(user_sessions)) \
                            .field("num_transactions",random.choice(num_xactions)) \
                            .time(int(time.mktime(time.localtime()))))
        #print(local)

        write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=points)
        # print(points[0].time())
        sleep(5)
```

Every 5 seconds I'm printing out the same unix timestamp to the second.  How can I make sure it increments?  I figured simply calling it each time would change the timestamp?

Comment: If the printing you are refering to is the commented out `print(points[0].time())`, well, that's no surprise, you print 5 times the time of the first point. If you want to print the time of the last created one, that would be `print(points[-1].time())`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  It has nothing to do with what I'm printing.  I have the client enabled with debug so I can see, in stdout, what is being sent over the wire.  The time is not incrementing.